# Remove grouped variable rows when 1 group are all NA

Tags: r

The table is time series data where two sets of data with matching variables and time have been combined. One dataset "x" will sometimes have values that are all numeric, some NA, or all NA, while dataset "y" will never have NA values.

How can the rows from dataset "x" and "y" be removed when a variable from dataset "x" has only NA values?

```
var <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",
         "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b",
         "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c")
value <- c(1, 2, NA, 4, 3, 2,
           NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3,
           4, 2, 1, 2, 5, 4)
time <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,
          1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
          1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
dataset <- c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y",
             "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y",
             "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y")

Test.df <-data.frame(var, value, time, dataset)

   var value time dataset
   a     1    1       x
   a     2    2       x
   a    NA    3       x
   a     4    1       y
   a     3    2       y
   a     2    3       y
   b    NA    1       x
   b    NA    2       x
   b    NA    3       x
   b     3    1       y
   b     3    2       y
   b     3    3       y
   c     4    1       x
   c     2    2       x
   c     1    3       x
   c     2    1       y
   c     5    2       y
   c     4    3       y
```

The desired result looks like:

```
   var value time dataset
    a     1    1       x
    a     2    2       x
    a    NA    3       x
    a     4    1       y
    a     3    2       y
    a     2    3       y
    c     4    1       x
    c     2    2       x
    c     1    3       x
    c     2    1       y
    c     5    2       y
    c     4    3       y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
> Test.df %>% filter(!all(is.na(value[dataset == "x"])), .by = var)
   var value time dataset
1    a     1    1       x
2    a     2    2       x
3    a    NA    3       x
4    a     4    1       y
5    a     3    2       y
6    a     2    3       y
7    c     4    1       x
8    c     2    2       x
9    c     1    3       x
10   c     2    1       y
11   c     5    2       y
12   c     4    3       y
```

Comment: That does it, thanks so much for the guidance.

Could you explain the `value[dataset == "x"]` please? It is referring to two columns in the condition for `is.na`?

Comment: @Methos that subsets `value`s corresponding to `x`s in the column `dataset`